How to pass an absolute path to NodejsFunction
I am working with absolute file paths. I want to know how to pass that path to the entry property of NodejsFunction. I've been investigating but I can't solve this problem.
This is the structure of my folders
-libs
  - controller
    - incidentController.ts
    - index.ts
  - handlers
    - incident.ts
    - index.ts
  index.ts

I share my code with you.
tsconfig.json
{
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@customer": ["libs/index.ts"]
    }
}

index.ts (libs/controller)
export * from './incidentController';

index.ts (libs/handler)
export * from './incident';

index.ts (libs)
export * from './handlers/index';

incident.ts (libs/handler) - Lambda Handler
import { IncidentController } from '../controller/index';
export const handler: APIGatewayProxyHandler = async (event: any, context: any) => {
    const data = new IncidentController();
    return await data.GetIncidents();
}

createLambda.ts  -  Lambda
import { incident } from '@customer';

new NodejsFunction(this, functionName, {
    handler: 'handler',
    runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_18_X,
    //entry: path.join(__dirname, '../../../handler/incident.ts'), 
    entry: incident.handler.toString() // Error
    role,
    memorySize: 512
});

When deploying it shows the following error =>  Error: Only JavaScript or TypeScript entry files are supported.
Thank you!

I think you're looking for path.resolves
Taken from the page

The path.resolve() method resolves a sequence of paths or path segments into an absolute path.

path.resolve('/foo/bar', './baz');
// Returns: '/foo/bar/baz'

path.resolve('/foo/bar', '/tmp/file/');
// Returns: '/tmp/file'

path.resolve('wwwroot', 'static_files/png/', '../gif/image.gif');
// If the current working directory is /home/myself/node,
// this returns '/home/myself/node/wwwroot/static_files/gif/image.gif'

